# How to reduce decimal places in a matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to reduce the decimal place in this plot from 3 to 1.  I can't find any way to do this. I have tried defining the levels in a list as ints but floats are required and seem to automatically come up as 3 decimal places. Help.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect='equal')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)    
modelmap = flopy.plot.ModelMap(model=mf)
quadmesh = modelmap.plot_ibound()
linecollection = modelmap.plot_grid(alpha=0.01)
#set up array to show wetland location
if alt_coords!=None: #plot the wetland if altcoords provided
    wl_arr=np.zeros([mf.nrow,mf.ncol])
    for coord in alt_coords:
        wl_arr[coord[1],coord[2]]=1.0
    quadmesh=modelmap.plot_array(wl_arr, color='w', alpha=0.1)
riv = modelmap.plot_bc('RIV', color='b', plotAll=True)
quadmesh = modelmap.plot_bc('WEL', kper=1, plotAll=True)
levels=np.arange(40, 100, 3)
contour_set = modelmap.contour_array(hds, levels, colors='b')
plt.clabel(contour_set, inline=1, fontsize=14)
```

Comment: [matplotlib.pyplot.clabel](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html#matplotlib-pyplot-clabel) accepts an `fmt` argument. This arg allows you to set the label format. So, you can specify this arg and see if it works: `plt.clabel(contour_set, inline=1, fmt='%1.1f, fontsize=14)`.

Comment: Great! I've added as answer for others coming across a similar problem. You may accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[matplotlib.pyplot.clabel](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html#matplotlib-pyplot-clabel) accepts an `fmt` argument. This arg allows you to set the label format. So, you can specify this arg and see if it works: `plt.clabel(contour_set, inline=1, fmt='%1.1f', fontsize=14)`

Comment: What is the syntax for using the fmt format string? I can guess partially from the single example shown, but the documentation you link to says only this: "A format string for the label. Default is '%1.3f'".  In particular, what if I want comma separators?